# Hide Python console when running Tkinter script from shell command

Tags: python, windows, shell, console, tkinter

I have extended the file context menu in the Windows registry and added a shortcut to a Python script (which is a Tkinter window). It runs fine, but obviously with the Python console in the background. I tried to change the shell command from `python` to `pythonw` (and renaming the file to `.pyw`) but then Windows always simply opens the "open with..." dialog and not the script. If I copy-paste the shell command and run it from cmd, it works. Running the `.pyw` from the explorer also works fine, without console.

Why is the behavior different when running it in the shell command?

This is in my `.reg` setup file under the command key:

```
@="pythonw \"C:\\test_script.pyw\" \"%1\""
```